# Convert Distinguished Name to Canonical Name

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices, directoryentry

Using `System.DirectoryServices` (i.e. the `DirectoryEntry` class) is there a way to convert the `DistinguishedName` attribute to, or get the Canonical Name that would normally appear in the *Active Directory Users & Computers* snap-in? I realize I could do this using regular expressions, but I would prefer a more reliable approach.

For example, I want to convert this

> CN=Murdock\, James,OU=Disabled Users,OU=GOG,DC=contoso,DC=local

to this

> contoso.local/GOG/Disabled Users/Murdock, James

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a constructed attribute.  On a DirectoryEntry, you need to use RefreshCache:

```
var de = new DirectoryEntry("CN=Murdock\, James,OU=Disabled Users,OU=GOG,DC=contoso,DC=local");
de.RefreshCache(new string[] {"canonicalName"});
```

Comment: And using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` ? *UserPrincipal.DistinguishedName*

Comment: You'll need to put that in its own question - TPTB at Stackoverflow don't like supplementary questions in comments.  By all means add a link here to the new question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want the canonicalName attribute. Assuming you already have the code for getting the user as a DirectoryEntry.

```
userDe.Properties["canonicalName"][0].ToString()
```

Comment: That property does not exist. At least not in my environment.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more thorough.  "canonicalName" is a property that has to be specified. It is a constructed property and doesn't seem to be returned with a standard DE object (sorry, should've checked first).  If you're using SDS you can use DirectorySearcher and PropertiesToLoad.Add("canonicalName") to grab the value.